# Android tts synthesizeToFile doesnt work

Tags: android, file-io, text-to-speech

Im trying to save the speech to wav output file.Nothing works.It returns -1.
I tried to check if storage writeable by:

```
    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

it returns True.

I tried to create dir with MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE premission and wtire to it.- doesnt work

I tried to give WRITEABLE premission in the manifest - doesnt work

```
<uses-permission
 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
 android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

Please help me
what should i do?
Thanks a lot

P.s the Play method works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the int returned by the `TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile`?

Are you sure about the path given by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory`? You can try to set the path manually by something like `/storage/sdcard0/myTts.wav` and search for that file with a file manager app. I really had trouble finding my synthesized files on my phone as well, due to the wierd behaviour of android saving files to the external sd card.

Another problem i faced using Tts is the restriction to strings with maximum 4000 characters. But as long as your `.speak` method is working this should not be the problem.

Comment: The method return -1.How did u solve the 4000 chars limit?Im plannig to record long sentences.@julian

Comment: Ok so the `.synthesizeToFile` does not synthesize anything at all. Since replacing it with `.speak` does work, i guess this must be a filesystem problem. Did you try setting the path to the wav-file manually? I solved the char restriction problem splitting my texts into smaller pieces by using a [StringTokenizer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot jullian.You were right.Its was somthing about the filesystem.New directory solved it "getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "newWavFile.wav""

Comment: Maybe the synthesizeToFile() returns TextToSpeech.SUCCESS but there is no file i can play.I created a new file for a same directory and checked if its true using isFile().What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

1)First create your path

```
boolean file = new File("give your path here").mkdirs();
```

2)Your file name

```
String destination_file_name = {"gave your path"}+"Your_file_name";
```

3)Let String Converting_Sting be your string to convert

```
String Converting_Sting;
```

4)Let get the max capacity of your text to speech engine

```
TextToSpeech tts;
```

int max_capacity_tts=tts.getMaxSpeechInputLength();

5)if your convert string length greater than max capacity you have to reduce the length

```
    if(Converting_Sting.length()>max_capacity_tts())
      {
       Converting_Sting.substring(0,max_capacity_tts);
      }
```

4)Then you can place the reduced string in the tts engine

```
 HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap();
                    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, parsedText);
                    tts.synthesizeToFile(Converting_Sting,params,destinationFileName+".wav");
```

Dont fogot to gave write permission on manifest

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

**(-1)** error when you use **synthesizeToFile** method using **targetsdkversion**  **29**, but when you have **targetsdkversion** less or equals **28** it works fine pls chekc latest update

```
   private void makeRingtoneFilename(String texttoconvertIntoAudiFile) {

    File saveFilePath = null;
    try {
        String rootPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/media/audio/ringtones/";
        File root = new File(rootPath);
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        saveFilePath = new File(rootPath + "niceSong.m4a");
        if (saveFilePath.exists()) {
            saveFilePath.delete();
        }
        saveFilePath.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    int i1;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
        //texttoconvertIntoAudiFile is the text you want to convrt into mp3
        i1 = textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile( texttoconvertIntoAudiFile, null,saveFilePath, null );
    } else {
        i1 = textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile( texttoconvertIntoAudiFile, null, String.valueOf( saveFilePath.getAbsoluteFile() ) );
    }
    Log.e( "i1", i1 + "" );


    String outPath=saveFilePath.getAbsolutePath();
    String mimeType;
    if (outPath.endsWith(".m4a")) {
        mimeType = "audio/mp4a-latm";
    } else if (outPath.endsWith(".wav")) {
        mimeType = "audio/wav";
    } else {
        // This should never happen.
        mimeType = "audio/mpeg";
    }

    String artist = "hum h yum";
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put( MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, outPath);
    values.put( MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "niceSong.m4a");
    values.put( MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
    values.put( MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, artist);
    values.put( MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE,FILE_KIND_RINGTONE);
    // Insert it into the database
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(outPath);
    final Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().setData(newUri));
}
```